# How Can I Display My Date Format As Day/Month/Year Instead Of Date And Time In Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

How can I display my date format as `day/month/year` instead of date and time in repeater?
Actually, I'm using this format in repeater:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DATE1","{0:d}")%>
```

The result is showing as `2014-12-11T00:00:00+05:30`

Please help me to display only the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
[BoundField.DataFormatString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("dateTime")).ToString("d") %>
```

or try

```
<%#Eval("dbDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>
```

or try

```
String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", myDateTimeInstance);
```

Comment: <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("dateTime")).ToString("d") %>  its working.Thank you so much.

Comment: After host the application format of date in repeater is changing.Now i'm gettin format as 11/25/2014.   I want date format as 25-11-2014. Please help me.